# If statement to display specific alert dialog

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I have an alert dialog to display when a state is finished. This dialog box displays the score and a high score. Is there way to display a specific alert dialog when a statement is true?

```
 AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setMessage("Score: " + Score + " High Score: " + highScore)
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.returnString, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), GameState.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
    return builder.create();
```

I tried this below but does not work and just crashes the app.

```
     if(Score > highScore) {
        builder.setMessage("You have set a new high score: " + highScore)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.returnString, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),GameState.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });
```

And then the else would contain the first set of code to just display the score and current high score.

Comment: What kind of Object is Score? And what are the messages of the crash?

Comment: @Martin They are both ints

Comment: Even the class Integer needs a method ( ´intValue()´ ) to get a "real" int.

Comment: can you add the logcat crash/stacktrace messages here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should work for you:

```
String message = "Score: " + Score + " High Score: " + highScore;
if(Score > highScore) {
    message = "You have set a new high score: " + highScore;
}
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
builder.setMessage(message)
        .setPositiveButton(R.string.returnString, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), GameState.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
return builder.create();
```

This would solve the conditional message display problem. However, it would be great if you add logcat output to the question so that any other error if present can also be identified.

Comment: This is what I wanted. I can't believe I hadn't thought of this. This works perfectly. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Glad could help :)